# How to style a border button to have width matched to the text above in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to style a border button to have width matched to the text above in CSS?

I want to clean before and after the navigation selected text, to match the border-bottom to the text above, like the example below.

Here what I have so far:

```css
.nav-link {
    padding-right: 29px;
    padding-left: 29px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.53);
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.nav-link.active {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;
    color:  #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav role="navigation" class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link active item">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Five</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Six</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Seven</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: use margin instead of padding in `.nav-link` class selector.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `padding-right` and `padding-left` use `margin-right` and `margin-left`.

```
.nav-link {
    margin-right: 29px;   /*use margin-right */
    margin-left: 29px;    /*use margin-left */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.53);
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```css
.nav-link {
    margin-right: 29px;
    margin-left: 29px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.53);
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.nav-link.active {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;
    color:  #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav role="navigation" class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link active item">Cupertino</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">New York City</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">London</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Amsterdam</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Tokyo</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Hong Kong</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Sydney</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

To remove the underline from all hyperlinks( tag) use `text-decoration:none;`

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-right: 29px;
  margin-left: 29px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.53);
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav role="navigation" class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link active item">Cupertino</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link item">New York City</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link item">London</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Amsterdam</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Tokyo</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Hong Kong</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link item">Sydney</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help you?

```css
.nav-link.active {
 border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.53);
 box-shadow: inset -29px 0 0 0 #fff, inset 29px 0 0 0 #fff, inset 0 -1px 0 0 #000;
 color:  #000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question correctly, you can just add the class that you use for the Css you applied to the nav bar. To the other element. For example

tokyo

You can use the "css-style" class and apply it to the other element you wqnt the css to be applied

Then use

Css-style:active
{
\codes here for active
}